# Uploading file to spreadsheet requires special permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script for Google Sheets which opens a form for uploading a file, and calls server-side function to handle the uploaded file. The problem I have is that the server-side function does not get called and failure handler is invoked with error message saying that I have no permissions to do the operation.
If I call the server side function with null argument instead of passing in the form then the function successfully gets called.

Here is the script I have:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Process bank statement file", functionName: "openUploadPaymentsDialog"}];
  ss.addMenu("AG_Menu", csvMenuEntries);
}

function openUploadPaymentsDialog(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UploadPaymentsDialog');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Upload .NDA file');
  Logger.log('dialog opened');
}

function handleFileUpload(theForm) {
  Logger.log('file uploaded');      
}
```

And HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="theFile"/><br/><br/>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="onSubmit(this.parentNode);"/>
    </form>
    <div id="output"/>
    <script>
      function onSubmit(theForm) {
        google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
                .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
                .handleFileUpload(theForm);
//if I call handleFileUpload with null as argument then call succeeds
      }

      function onFailure(error){
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
      }

      function onSuccess(f){
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The script is bound to the spreadsheet and I'm not the owner of the spreadsheet, but I have permissions to edit. I'm running the script from my user (not owner).

Is it so that only owner can upload files? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is probably some problem with browser I'm using. It is Google Chromium under Debian Linux. I have just tried it with Firefox and it works OK.